# Using functions like formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2002, vba

I am trying to use a formula to get a letter of the alphabet.

Formula:

```
=Keytable(RANDOM,ROW())
```

Function:

```
Function KeyTable(seed As Long, position As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Stop
    Dim calpha(1 To 26) As String
    Dim alpha(1 To 26) As String

    For i = 1 To 26
        alpha(i) = Chr(i + UPPER_CASE - 1)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 26
        calpha(i) = alpha(seed Mod 27 - i)
    Next i
    Stop
    KeyTable = calpha(position)
End Function
```

Result:

```
#Value!
```

When I step through the function, it never gets to the second stop. What is wrong?

Comment: I would think it is the `Stop` word on the 3rd line...

Comment: Is this code trying to return a random letter of the alphabet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RANDOM` is not a function in Excel.  `RAND()` is and it returns a `float` between 0 and 1.  You need an `integer` to do modulus calculations.

To get a random integer, use:

```
INT ((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * RAND() + lowerbound)
```

Then, once `seed Mod 27 - i` becomes 0 or less, the function dies because arrays can't be indexed with 0 or less in VBA (or most languages).

---

But really all you need to do for a random letter is this:

```
=CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,90))
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! It should be noted that you need the Analysis Toolpak for that (RandBetween).

Answer (score 0):

This code will return random letter of alphabet:

```
Function GetLetter()
    Dim letters As String
    Dim randomIndex As Byte

    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    randomIndex = Int((26 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1) //Get random number between 1 and 26

    GetLetter = VBA.Mid$(letters, randomIndex, 1)
 End Function
```

Comment: What is the `(26 - 1 + 1)` all about?

Comment: The general formula for a random number between two numbers is: Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)). We want a random number bewteen 1 and 26 for the alphabet so just plug into the equation. NB - the Int is there to make sure number is a whole number.